# Constraints wildcard subdomain

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

How can I route all subdomains to a controller in a Rails app?

I though something like this would work, but it doesn't:

```
constraints :subdomain => '*' do
  get '/', :to => 'frontend#index'
  mount API => '/api'
end
```

Subdomains like

```
foo.example.com
bar.example.com
```

should be directed to `frontend#index` while

```
foo.example.com/api
bar.example.com/api
```

should call the Grape API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a regular expression:

```
constraints :subdomain => /./ do...
```

Haven't tested it, but something like that should work.

Comment: Whoops sorry! Edited my answer!

Comment: This seems to no longer work? Or can this not be used with scope's? getting no route matches...